# Will I miss something if I uninstall Growl off Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, notifications, growl

I updated to Mountain Lion more than a year ago.

Even before that, Growl has been annoying me with a pop-up asking me to update.

The new version is costs 4 USD in the App Store.

Since ML has notifications:

- Should I care for Growl anymore ?
- Would I'll be missing something if I unistall Growl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was an avid user of Growl before Mountain Lion. I started a fresh install without growl and all my apps that were using growl have been updated to use the built in notifications.

Unless there is something specific you need from the growl features I doubt you'll miss it.

Comment: I agree. Apple bringing Notification Center to OS X has all but replaced apps like Growl.